# The [html] tag should have lang-html as it's highlight language

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

If you look at the tag wikis for [`[html]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info) and [`[html5]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5/info) you will find that they both have

> Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): default

at the bottom, indicating they have no syntax highlighting. This should be changed to `lang-html`.

### workaround

For now, the [Syntax Highlighting Instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/364344) have a list of prettify language codes that you can use, and so if, for instance, your entire question is about html, you can use:

```html
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, the problem with specifying an explicit syntax highlighting for a tag like [html] is that it's commonly used with other tags, like [css] and [javascript], which could lead to syntax-highlighting conflicts. Better to let Prettify make a best-guess, and manually override with hints when necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They *do* have syntax highlighting, 'default' does not mean 'none'. See [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

> - ***Default: let Prettify interpret the code and guess***
>     `default`
> - ***None: explicitly do not use any syntax highlighting***
>     `lang-none`

Prettify is capable of detecting the code blocks as HTML. We could assign `lang-html` but it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: oh, I wonder why it wasn't working for me? maybe because I was trying to do a code block inside of a blockquote?

Comment: Can you share a link to the post where it didn't work?